# Asp.net MVC Hosting - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

So I'm moving my Asp.net mvc web app over to Arvixe shared hosting.  This is the first time I've deployed an MVC app.  I have been using SQL Server 2008 Express for the development database.  Arvixe provides SQL Server 2008 or MySQL hosted databases.

A couple questions:

1.Can I use the mdf files from my Express database with the new Non-Express prodcution DB?

2.I'm having issues with my connection string. I changed the original web config connection string from this:

```
<add name="Database1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to this:

```
<add name="Database1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ProdsDB"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now I'm getting this error:
Cannot open database "ProdsDB" requested by the login. The login failed

I have setup the database called "ProdsDB" through the Arvixe control panel and added one user.  Do I need to add the credentials somewhere in the connection string?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You're going to need to add `User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;` to the connection string, and you'll need to remove `Integrated Security=SSPI`

Of course, you'll need to set them to the username and password you created.  Also, sometimes hosting providers host the database on a separate server.  If that's the case, you'll have to specify the servername in place of the dot.